# Remap arrow keys to win+ijkl on linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, keyboard-layout, autohotkey

I'd like to remap arrow keys to **windows** key plus **ijkl**.  I can do this easily in Autohotkey on windows, but I'm struggling on Linux (Ubuntu lucid).

I'd really like the solution to work independently of whether I'm using a window manager or not, and to involve modifying as few files as possible; I work on a lots of different machines and am always building new ones, so would like to minimise reconfig effort.

I've tried to understand .Xmodmap, but couldn't make it work (was hard to find detailed docs on modifier keys).

(Am also considering win+hjkl, but am probably not that hardcore)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use xev to find out the key code for the modifier key(Win key in this case).

Let it be 66.

Make a file named Xmodmap (or whatever you like) with the following content.

```
keycode 66 = Mode_switch
keysym j = j J Left 
keysym l = l L Right
keysym i = i I Up
keysym k = k K Down
```

Now load these mappings using xmodmap Xmodmap

Comment: This was exactly what I needed. Thanks very much.

Comment: What if I press ctrl+mode_switch+j? It should behave as if I pressed ctrl+left, but it does not (it acts as if I pressed ctrl+j). How can I fix this?

Comment: Solution 2 here https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/434143/258952 was the best option for me!

Comment: Tiny bit of additional information for those who may not find it obvious. You can load the mappings in your `~/.profile` file so that they are ready on login. Cheers

Answer (score 4):

Slight variation of @yaniv's answer mapped for VIM shortcuts

> keycode 66 = Mode_switch
>  keysym h = h H Left
>  keysym l = l L
>   Right
>  keysym k = k K Up
>  keysym j = j J Down

Also you might want to have your xmodmap run on every login.

Answer (score 2):

Install [xbindkeys](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xbindkeys) [image: Install xbindkeys] to assign meanings to keys,
[xmacro](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xmacro) [image: Install xmacro] for the meaning to be like typing another key,
and [xbindkeys-config](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xbindkeys-config) [image: Install xbindkeys-config] for a configuration interface to xbindkeys. There is a good explanation on the [keyboard shortcuts](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KeyboardShortcuts#Replacing%20keys%20with%20other%20keys) page in the Ubuntu community documentation.